# ¿Cómo dar prioridad a un método en un serializer de Django?

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework

Cuando hago una peticion http, necesito que el método `create()` se ejecute antes que `get_price()`. ¿Alguien tiene idea de cómo se puede hacer esto?

```
class OrderDetailedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

    def get_price(self, obj):

        # ...

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo ejecutarlo al final del metodo save de esta forma

```
class OrderDetailedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

    def get_price(self, obj):

        # ...

    def create(self, validated_data):

        # ...

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super.save(self, **kwargs)
        self.getPrice(self.instance)
        return self.instance
```